# Шейдеры: Зачем нужна матрица нормалей (normalMatrix), и как её найти?

Tags: opengl, шейдеры, glsl

В различных примерах код шейдеров содержит разные `uniform` с такими матрицами преобразований: `mat4 projMatrix` (матрица проекции), `mat4 viewMatrix` (матрица преобразований камеры), `mat4 modelMatrix` (матрица преобразований модели) и какую-то матрицу нормалей: `mat4 normalMatrix`. Что она обозначает, где её взять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Как её найти?

Матрица преобразования нормалей относится к отдельным объектам и легко вычисляется на основе матрицы преобразований модели:

```
mat4 normalMatrix = transpose(inverse(modelMatrix));
```

Однако излишне затратно производить такие вычисления в графическом процессоре, то есть, множество раз, поэтому обычно эта матрица вычисляется лишь раз в основном коде и затем передаётся в OpenGL посредством `uniform`.

---

## Зачем она нужна?

Дело в том, что матрицу преобразования модели иногда некорректно использовать для её нормалей. Возьмём такую ситуацию: есть треугольник, в нём вектор **T** и нормаль к нему **N**:

[image: before]

При масштабировании по вертикали, нормаль теряет перпендикулярность к стороне треугольника:

[image: after]

Другими словами, если матрица [ортогональная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0) (т.е, равна обратной и транспонированной версии себя), то такие виды преобразований, как вращение и смещение не меняют этого свойства. Но это не касается масштабирования не равного по всем осям. Именно поэтому если Вы используете такое масштабирование, или Ваш код предназначен для других людей, то следует использовать транспонирование от обратной матрицы преобразования модели.

---

## Полезные ссылки

- [Аналогичный вопрос на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079741/5308802)
- [Статья по теме (eng)](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-12-tutorial/the-normal-matrix/)
- [Являются ли normalMatrix и modelMatrix одинаковыми?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/126115) (GameDev StackExchange)

Comment: То есть нужно это только если модель планируется масштабировать непропорционально по осям?

Comment: @Kromster добавил деталей в ответ; в целом, да, так и есть.